# How do I pass a bearer token in a WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Application to be able to call an API in WSO2 API Publisher?

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 and would like to call an API at the end of a WSO2 ESB application that transfers files to be able to send a notification to a messaging service which is what the API does. I am unsure of how to pass the bearer token in the xml of the ESB application to call the api endpoint and authorize the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property mediator to send an Authorization header

```
<property name="Authorization" value="Bearer 1234-1234-11111" scope="transport" />
```

Put this before the `<endpoint>` block and it'll send an Authorization Header with the Bearer token 1234-1234-11111 to the backend.

Comment: Ok awesome and is there a way to regenerate the token when the endpoint is called so as to avoid hard coding it in but rather fetching a new one everytime so if it expires then itll have the most recent one that works?

Comment: You can use Token API (https://localhost:8243/token) to generate a token each time you call the backend. But this too would require keeping Consumer Key/Secret pair in the ESB. When you say you are calling API in API Publisher, do you mean that it's a developer API in the portal (the ones called by Publisher UI)?

Comment: So I have tested it using a bash script calling the ...:8243/token to set the header with a new token before calling the backend but what I am struggling with is how to implement that same logic in the actual code of the ESB sequence. Its okay that I need to keep the Key/Secret pair in the ESB but do you know the code that would achieve this? What I mean by saying Im calling the API in API Publisher is that it was published there, I havent created the API as part of the ESB application which is what I have seen in a lot of examples. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Better option would be to write a custom mediator for this. You can follow this document to get an idea about this https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java. So the code inside mediator would read consumer key/secret call the Token API and get a new token. Additionally token can be cached to prevent unnecessary calls to Token API.